# KineticJS: Gap between shapes on certain scales

Tags: kineticjs

When I put two rects side by side in layer and set a scale on that layer I'll get a gap between these two rects.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wT5F3mqstZWp5T66qeoU?p=preview

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

**[Edit]**

Take a look here:

http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/09/handling-floating-point-coordinates-with-pixels-in-svg-html5-canvas/

The problem comes from a rounding error in the float point position when scaling.

```
  var ctx=document.getElementById("cvs").getContext("2d");

  // Position rounding error
  ctx.fillStyle="green";
  ctx.lineWidth=0;
  ctx.fillRect(0,5,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(0.25,10,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(0.5,15,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(0.75,20,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(1,25,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(5,5,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(5.25,10,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(5.5,15,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(5.75,20,5,5);
  ctx.fillRect(6,25,5,5);
```

When the position is not an integer what it seems to do the browser is to set an alpha fading of 1 pixel with an alpha proportional to the non integer part. When you place this two bands together the result is not the full color (i dunno why they have decide so) as you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/siliconball/7JPdV/

The rect in you example have an initial position of 4.

```
  var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 4,
    y: 4,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
  });
```

Then when the layer is scaled by 1.6 the final result of the new x is 4 * 1.6 = 6.4. This makes to appear the rounding error and produce this gap effect between the 2 layers. If the initial position is 0, 5, 10, 15,.. then there is no gap as the rounding error in this positions are 0.

```
  var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 5,
    y: 4,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
  });
```

A possible way to fix this issue would be to set the position once the layer it have been scaled and by considering the scaling factor when doing so. I cannot think on any more advices as I don't know the details of your applications but looks like (wish i'm wrong) this is a problem that it cannot be solved in a straight way.

Comment: Thanks. But now you've modified the shape which I cannot do. In my real use case I load images within these rects so I cannot have a stroke.

Comment: I see. Looks like the real problem comes from the scaling of the layer.